# Cmd Does Not Prompt tThe Output of The Python File

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a simple python document which takes --n or --name attribute to display a simple output.

My code is below

```py
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-n", "--name", required=True,
    help="name of the user")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


print("Hi there {}, it's nice to meet you!".format(args["name"]))
```

When I run this python code with cmd (D:\User\Name> python filename.py --name Name) I don't get any output, while I aim to get the output Hi there Name, it's nice to meet you! What am I missing here?

Comment: A script based on your code snippet runs smoothly for me (tried `py -2`, `py -3.5` as well as `py -3.8`).

Comment: My reading of the question @JosefZ, is an intention to run `"P:\ath To\python.exe" "L:\ocation Of\filename.py" -n Josef` or `"P:\ath To\python.exe" "L:\ocation Of\filename.py" --name Josef`.

Comment: @Compo :) My reading of the question is _When I run this python code with cmd (`python filename.py --name Name`) **I don't get any output**_.

Comment: @JosefZ, okay, so the examples `py -2`, `py -3.5`, and  `py -3.8` are trying to explain that you've tested the provided code in three different versions of python, and it has worked smoothly in all. I apologize for the confusion, I misread your comment as a shortening of  `filename.py -n`, to `py -2` etc. If you cannot replicate the issue, especially with three different versions of python, should you not have at least voted to close the question, as not reproducible?

Comment: I don't see how you could get no output at all, as this code clearly has a print statement.  You must be running other code that you haven't shown us.